# How to switch between two different Tab Bar Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have two tab bar controllers, one for each type of user which provides specific functions depending on the type of user. It works on a similar concept such as Uber (driver, customer) or Airbnb (host, customer). I have a sideBar menu where users can switch between these two interfaces. I use the SWReavelController library for my sideBar menu. Whenever I segue from the old tab view controller to the new one (setting the segue from the button in the sideBar to the new Tab view controller as 'SWRevealPushController' ), it shows the view controller of my new tab bar Controller but the tab doesn't change and still allows me to access elements of the old tab. Any suggestions on how to cure this?

Comment: provide some code to understand the problem.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich Not really any code since you use custom segues with the SWReaveal Library. The only code is in the viewDidLoad method of the view controllers you segue to. If I have a bar button item named 'menu' then in the viewDidLoad method i would have: `                 if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        }
`